# show content type fields from user on another content type

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I need to be able to show fields from one content type on another.

Example:

Article: basic title/body fields
Author Bio: User information (website, twitter and FB info, email, etc... fields)

Trying to create a block that will look at the NID, pull the node author and show the bio at the bottom of the node.

I tried using UID and NID as the contextual filter and author as the relationship. I also filtered to show only published and content type "author bio"

But when I try and use the auto preview, I get my labels with no data.

So I went into the individual fields, but there is no drop down to force a relationship to the node author like in entity references.

I am missing something, but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it may be better to just add all personal info fields to the User entity itself instead of creating a whole new Content Type (go to Configuration > People > Account settings and add fields such as website, twitter, etc to the user entity). Then simply create a view of articles and create a relationship to the user entity by choosing `Content: Author`. Then simply add user fields to your list of fields in the view. Am I missing something in your question? (it's not very clear). Let me know and I can edit this answer.

**Edit after your comment:** Since you are interested in providing these info fields to specific users, I would then explore the [profile2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2), which allows you to add additional fields for certain users. You can create different profile types with different fields, and allow certain roles to have access to specific profiles. In your View you can create a relationship to `Content: Author` first, and then one to the profile, then add those profile2 fields to your list of fields in the view.

Otherwise, if you still want to do this with a Author bio content type, I would suggest that you add an Entity Reference field to the User, and then you can use that as a bridge to your Article. Let me know if you want more details on this.

Comment: I am mainly doing this because not all roles will have access to it and creating a content type allows separation and role access.

Comment: OK, so, can you clarify why the vote against this answer???

Comment: Similar comment: don't worry ...